# How can you deduce from the structure that probenecid is an acid and ephedrine is a base?

Tags: acid-base

Probenecid contains a carboxyl group, indicating an acid. But it also contains a nitrogen atom, which indicates a base? How can I decide that it is an acid and not a base?
[image: Probenecid]
[image]

I have the same problem with the ephedrine structure.

Answer (score 4):

The nitrogen atom in Probenecid is not part of a basic functional group (eg: amine), but of another kind of functional group: sulfonamide.

Sulfonamides are, just like amides, quite acidic: the presence of an electron-withdrawing group next to the nitrogen atom makes the electron pair less available, and makes the functional group quite acidic (see Lewis' definition of acids and bases).

For comparison, ammonium has a pKa of around 9, amides have a pKa above 15.

Sharing with amides the presence of an electron withdrawing group, sulfonamides can be expected to share the same acidic behaviour of amides.

You should check pKa list for the functional groups you have studied.

An example of such chart:

http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf
(Be careful: values between parentheses are referred to the acidity in DMSO).

To better understand the delocalization of the electron pair in amides, see:
https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Amides/Properties_of_Amides/Structure_of_Amides

Answer (score 3):

Probenecid, also sold under the brandname Probalan ,has two functional groups Sulfonamide and carboxylic acid.In Sulfonamide , lone pair on N are involved in resonance with sulphur.Such resonance gives 1 and 2 .In these N possess positive charge rendering it less basic.Coupling with stearic hindrance factors N is considerablly less basic.

[image]

However,

Carboxylic acid is stabilized by resonance (structure 3) and also an electron withdrawing group at para position that enhances stability of carboxylate ion.

[image]

Taking the above factors into account ,with stearic hindrance and conjugation decreasing basic nature of amine and resonance stabilization of carboxylate ion ,Probenecid has acidic nature.

**Referances**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZhaj.png)   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probenecid

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Wim.png)  https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01032